How to configure OpenApi Generator with Swagger UI
If one wants to generate the code from an openapi file, OpenApi Generator Plugin for Maven is quite handy.
I am using the OpenAPI Generator Plugin for Maven to generate server code for a demo Spring Boot application created with  Spring Initializr. When the interfaceOnly flag is set to false, the generator creates a SpringDocConfiguration class that includes a bean for io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI, which the Swagger UI uses. However, it also generates an org.openapitools.OpenApiGeneratorApplication class with a @SpringBootApplication annotation. This class conflicts with my DemoApplication.java, which has its own @SpringBootApplication annotation.
when I try to build the project, I encounter the following error due to multiple main classes:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.2.5:repackage (repackage) on project demo: Execution repackage of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.2.5:repackage failed: Unable to find a single main class from the following candidates [org.openapitools.OpenApiGeneratorApplication, com.example.demo.DemoApplication] -> [Help 1]

How can I ignore the OpenApiGeneratorApplication.java file during generation? I would like to check out the java class annotated with @SpringBootApplication to have better control.
My pom.xml is configured as follows:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>22</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-models</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <configHelp>false</configHelp>
                            <inputSpec>
                                ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/petstore.yaml
                            </inputSpec>
                            <openapiGeneratorIgnoreList>OpenApiGeneratorApplication.java</openapiGeneratorIgnoreList>
                            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                            <apiPackage>com.example.demo.api</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>com.example.demo.api.model</modelPackage>
                            <configOptions>
                                <useSpringBoot3>true</useSpringBoot3>
                                <delegatePattern>false</delegatePattern>
                                <interfaceOnly>false</interfaceOnly>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>           
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

I tried to use the openapi-generator-ignore file but together with the property openapiGeneratorIgnoreList, but it still generates the class.
For easy testing I will temporarily leave this project to checkout: [git@github.com:legolaz8451/openapi-generator-spring-demo.git](git@github.com:legolaz8451/openapi-generator-spring-demo.git)

To avoid the generation of the @SpringBootApplication class from Spring, one has to add the class to the openapiGeneratorIgnoreList inside the configuration element like this:
<openapiGeneratorIgnoreList>
  src/main/java/org/openapitools/OpenApiGeneratorApplication.java
</openapiGeneratorIgnoreList>

source

I put the path to an ignore file in the maven generator configuration:
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      ...
      <executions>
        <execution>
          ...
          <configuration>
            ...
            <ignoreFileOverride>.openapi-generator-ignore</ignoreFileOverride>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>

The generator creates this file by default. You should read it -- it has instructions for how to use it, but it basically works like git's .ignore file. The generated file gets overwritten each time you generate code, so you need to create your own, at the path you specify in the .pom file.
If you're generating the code in a submodule, you may want to express the property like this:
<ignoreFileOverride>
  ${project.basedir}/.openapi-generator-ignore
</ignoreFileOverride>

This lets you put the file in the base of the submodule, instead of the main module.
